# JAX-WS MTOM does not work on Tomcat but works if published by Endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to send an attachment from JAX-WS/Metro server to a client.

I have a standard Tomcat 7/JDK 6 environment and simple project generated from WSDL with single operation.

Many guides say how to configure MTOM, I added base64Binary type to my response and @MTOM anotation to my service implementation. I did not add anything else.

When I call

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/sampleService", new SampleService()); ;
    }
```

It works fine and I see attachments coming from the server.

Now I want to create a web app that does the same thing.

Here is part of my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SampleService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SampleService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SampleService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I downloaded jaxws-ri dependencies and put them inside Tomcat/lib folder.
Also created the following sun-jaxws.xml in WEB-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
    version="2.0">

    <endpoint
        name="SampleService"
        implementation="com.example.SampleService"
        url-pattern="/SampleService"
        mtom-enabled="true"
         />

</endpoints>
```

Notice *mtom-enabled* property.

Then I deployed it and it works, but MTOM does not work, responses contain  inlined Base64-encoded binary data instead of attachments.
The code is exactly the same, the difference is only the way of running it and additional web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml files.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, eventually I could solve it, in my case the MTOM was disabled because a custom handler serialized the soap message which is not invoked when I used the direct jax-ws service. 
So try to disable all the implementation LogicalHandler and SOAPHandler 
in our case we set up the handlers in the web service config:

```
final SpringService springService = new SpringService();
springService.setBean(endpoint);
springService.setHandlers(getHandlers());
```

where getHandlers was private List getHandlers();

I hope it helps.